# DeExpress MVC 17.1 How populate TokenBox from a database

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I want populate a TokenBox from a database using the property *tokenBoxSettings.Properties.DataSource*

**TokenBoxView.cshtml**

```
 groupSettings.Items.Add(
                        formLayoutSettings.Items.Add(i =>
                        {
                            i.FieldName = "email";
                            i.Caption = "Email";
                            i.NestedExtensionType = FormLayoutNestedExtensionItemType.TokenBox;
                            TokenBoxSettings tokenBoxSettings = (TokenBoxSettings) i.NestedExtensionSettings;
                            tokenBoxSettings.Width = 350;
//data binding
        tokenBoxSettings.Properties.DataSource = mainController.GetMails();
                            tokenBoxSettings.Properties.TextField = "email_empresarial";
                            tokenBoxSettings.Properties.ValueField = "email_empresarial";
                            tokenBoxSettings.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
                            tokenBoxSettings.Properties.ValueSeparator = ';';
                        })
                        );
```

**TokenBoxController.cs**

```
//mainController
//I created a dictionary based on the result of select
public Dictionary<string, string> GetMails()
        {
            var email = db.usuario.ToList().Select(e => new { e.email_empresarial });
            var emails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var mail in email)
            {
                correos.Add(mail.ToString(), mail.ToString());
            }
            return emails;
}
```

But it shows me the "object explicitly", I only need the value, for example *kenneth* or *manuel*

[tokenBox list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZSc3.png)

What am I doing wrong? or with what other approach I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying same `email_empresarial` field name for both `tokenBoxSettings.Properties.TextField` and `tokenBoxSettings.Properties.ValueField`.

Since you are binding your TokenBox to Dictionary, try changing settings for `TextField` and `ValueField` to reference Dictionary Key and Value, like this:

```
tokenBoxSettings.Properties.TextField = "Value";
tokenBoxSettings.Properties.ValueField = "Key";
```

Also, in your `GetMail()` method you have declared the `var emails` but in the loop you are adding items to the undeclared `correos` variable. Are you sure you don't have a bug here?

Another note, in the Dictionary returned by `GetMails()` you populate both dictionary keys and values with the same value of `mail.ToString()`. Are you sure you really need to use Dictionary to bind your TokenBox? If keys and values are equal you may try going with plain `List<string>`.